# NuxtJS SSR - Cloudflare Firewall

Tags: nuxt.js, cloudflare

We have a NuxtJS application running in SSR mode on AWS Lambda connecting to a REST API sitting behind Cloudflare with rate limit rules enabled to protect certain routes.

When the NuxtJS app makes requests from the server side CloudFlare see's the Lambda container's IP rather than the client's IP. This results in requests being blocked incorrectly.

I've read through what little documentation I can find surrounding NuxtJS and CloudFlare to no avail. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction in the form of documentation or use case to tackle this problem?

Comment: Why are your server side requests hitting your CloudFlare firewall?

Comment: The server side requests are hitting our API which sits behind cloudflare - CloudFlare is getting the IP of the server sending the request instead of the client ip.

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need to figure out which request header the API server uses to validate requests and then change its value to the origin IP.

If the origin IP is available in your [request headers](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/logging-headers), you can use a Cloudflare Worker to [rewrite the headers](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/alter-headers) so that the origin IP replaces the necessary header's value instead of the Cloudflare IP.